# React progressbar on scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to create a react progressbar on scroll using the [react-progressbar-on-scroll](https://github.com/mleralec/react-progressbar-on-scroll/tree/master). And my [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-progressbar-on-scroll-7q3q3c) is working fine but not my local files, I can see the `ProgressBar` background linear-gradient percentage is not working properly in `element.style`. Nothing fancy here I don't have any idea why it is not working locally.

[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-progressbar-on-scroll-7q3q3c) `element.style`: See the `background: linear-gradient red percentage is dynamic onScroll and it is working properly here.`

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 8px; z-index: 999; top: 0px; bottom: unset; background: linear-gradient(to right, red 28%, transparent 0px);"></div>
```

Local `element.style`: See the `background: linear-gradient red percentage is dynamic onScroll and it is not working properly here.`

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 8px; z-index: 999; top: 0px; bottom: unset; background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, transparent 0px);"></div>
```

**Update:**
I think i know the reason why it is not working, it is because the html tag have 100% height. That 100% height is a part of my template and I don't want to remove it. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Here are my local files code:
**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import ProgressBar from 'react-progressbar-on-scroll';

import './App.scss';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <header>
          <div>Header Content</div>
        </header>

        <ProgressBar color="red" height={8}/>
        
        <main className="flex-shrink-0">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={
                <>
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<SuspenseLoader />}>
                    <div>Home Content</div>
                  </React.Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route path="*" element={
                <>
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<SuspenseLoader />}>
                    <div>Content Not Found!</div>
                  </React.Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
          </Routes>
        </main>

        <footer className="footer mt-auto">
          <div>Footer Content</div>
        </footer>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**package.json.**

```js
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.6.2",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.16",
    "react-progressbar-on-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the console if there are any errors?I also see that in sandbox you are using css and here you are using scss. Is the styles properly working on your local files

Comment: Ive just added additional info above. Console has no error and all the styles are working properly except for the ProgressBar.